# Blazor button onclick on desktop and ontouchstart on mobile

Tags: blazor, touch, touch-event, blazor-webassembly, preventdefault

I am using Blazor WebAssembly and I am trying to put a button on a web page which should work in desktop browsers using mouse, as well as mobile devices using touch. However, on mobile I want the button to respond to touch **immediately**, rather than wait for the user to let go.

Also I need to make sure it does not fire the same code twice on mobile, which is why I put the `preventDefault=true` in.

So I came up with the following:

```
<button
    @onclick="e => ToggleFlag(flag)"                                                
    @ontouchstart="e => ToggleFlag(flag)"
    @ontouchstart:preventDefault=true>
        @flag.DisplayValue
</button>
```

I thought the above code would work, but unfortunately Chrome is responding with the following "intervention" when I emulate the touch event:

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 [Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

After a bit more digging I found some useful info [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17358#issuecomment-558143503) and [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention#background_cancelable_events_slow_your_page_down).

What I take away from this, is that Blazor is registering its touch event listeners with `{passive: true}` by default which means Chrome will not allow the use of `preventDefault`, and as far as I am aware there is no way I can tell Blazor to use `{passive: false}`.

I have also tried removing `@ontouchstart:preventDefault=true` while applying the `touch-action: none;` style to the button, which didn't help as it just resulted in both listeners being called on touch.

What might be a possible solution here?

Thanks!

*ps. as a work-around I have resorted to duplicating the button (each listening to a different event) and using CSS media queries to show/hide the relevant button depending on whether we're in desktop or mobile mode. Not ideal IMO and feels like a bit of a hack.*